# Git S3 KeyError

Tags: git, amazon-s3, repository

I'm trying to set up [GitS3](http://wiki.cs.pdx.edu/oss2009/index/projects/gits3.html) to use git with s3. I'm simply not sure how to treat this error:

```
~/code/jumpin/pipe: python $GITS3/src/gits3/gits3.py push s31 refs/head/master
Local Refs:  refs/head/master
HEAD 8d1ccd43c5d7245c8376d8245f460ea554de5cab
refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 8d1ccd43c5d7245c8376d8245f460ea554de5cab
refs/remotes/origin/master 8d1ccd43c5d7245c8376d8245f460ea554de5cab
refs/heads/master 8d1ccd43c5d7245c8376d8245f460ea554de5cab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/frout/code/gits3/src/gits3/gits3.py", line 124, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/frout/code/gits3/src/gits3/gits3.py", line 93, in main
    updated_objects = client.get_updates(refs, tracking_ref)
  File "/Users/frout/code/gits3/src/gits3/local_repo.py", line 67, in get_updates
    local = refs[local_ref]
KeyError: 'refs/head/master'
```

Anyone knows what I need to fix?

I would also take recommendations for other good tools to do this smoothly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Considering this code](https://github.com/abdelhalim/gits3/blob/master/src/gits3/amazon_s3_transport.py#L149-L181) (which can raise a `KeyError`), this seems linked to an improper ref.

```
        # .git/HEAD
        if refs.startswith('refs/heads'):
            head_str = 'ref: ' + refs + '\n'
        else:
            head_str = 'refs: refs/heads/' + refs + '\n'
```

Try:

```
 python $GITS3/src/gits3/gits3.py push s31 refs/heads/master
                                                    ^
                                                    |
                                                    --- heads, not head
```

In [Git Internals: Git References](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References), `refs/heads` does exist, not `refs/head`.

Comment: That did it. But then another problem in the code came up. This thing is buggy as hell. Thanks VonC